# How to Match Paragraphs in Text with regx

Tags: regex, extract, match, paragraph

I need to extract all paragraphs from a text using regxp, so I figure to match first paragraph and iterate through all others, the problem I'm facing is I'm unable to make regxp to successfully match first paragraph, I would be forever grateful for help!

Comment: could you give a simple example please? input/output

Comment: Isnt a paragraph just one line???

Answer (score 5):

A Paragraph is a distinct section of a piece of writing,indicated by a new line, indentation, or numbering

So,you can do this

```
(\n|^).*?(?=\n|$)
```

Use this `regex` with singleline option

Comment: it works good, even better when I make it match only first paragraph, like this (^).*?(?=\n|$)